# Printing dynamically stored string in assembly mips32

Tags: string, assembly, printing, mips

I'm working on a mini-compiler and I reached the code generation level.
I want to store a string dynamically to the heap segment, so I wrote this C++ code (cg is the file I'm generating assembly code to) :

```
int length = strlen("abc");
cg << "\tori\t$a0,$0," << (length + 3) * 4 << endl; // reserve space for type + length + null + size
cg << "\tori\t$v0,$0,9" << endl;
cg << "\tsyscall" << endl;
increamentSP();
cg << "\tsw\t$v0,0($sp)" << endl;

cg << "\tori\t$t1,$0,1" << endl; // store the type
cg << "\tsw\t$t1,0($v0)" << endl;

cg << "\tori\t$t1,$0," << length << endl; // store the length
cg << "\tsw\t$t1," << 4 << "($v0)" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    cg << "\tori\t$t1,$0," << (int)p->val[i] << endl; // store the char
    cg << "\tsw\t$t1," << (2 + i) * 4 << "($v0)" << endl;
}
cg << "\tsw\t$0," << (2 + length) * 4 << "($v0)" << endl;
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is :
First, I want to store a flag (1) referring that this type is a string to the first location.
Then, I want to store the size of my string to the second location.
After that, I want to store my strings chars to the next locations.
Finally, I want to store a null-terminating char to the last location.
My problem is that when I try to print my string using a code like this :

```
la $a0,8($t0)
ori $v0,$0,4
syscall
```

The result is that mips prints only the letter 'a', how can I print a string stored like this? or is there any better way to store my string?
p.s. I know I can use `.asciiz` in the .data segment, but the problem is that in my code I might edit the string, so I don't exactly know what my string would become.
Can any one help me with that?

Comment: MIPS `la` is not like x86 `lea`. Like `li`, it's a pseudo-instruction that gets translated to something like `lui, ori`, and so it only loads *constant addresses*. `la $a0, 8($t0)` is meaningless, but maybe you meant `addi $a0, $t0, 8`?

Comment: yeah thanks that's what I need, but now it prints only the char `|`

Comment: Looks like you are storing 4 bytes per char, not 1 byte as usual? I doubt the syscall expects that. You probably want to rewrite your code so it has 1 byte per char. Use `sb` instruction to store them.